# What is the mistake in my code

Tags: android

I would like to have a Text plus image button in a row. if i add image button, and pro-grammatically align towards right side, still i will be able to see the background color of theme in my phone.

Here is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="0dp">

     <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


     <RelativeLayout
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal" 
         android:background="#041A37">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:text="All contact list" />


<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/Contact_icon"
    android:layout_width="45dip"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />


<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Contact_icon"
    android:ems="10"
    android:text="AutoCompleteTextView"
    android:visibility="invisible" >
    <requestFocus />
</AutoCompleteTextView>

    </RelativeLayout>

            <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="0dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

[image]

Here how the image looks, i want that button to cover the blue color border too.

Comment: Which XML element corresponds to the button you're talking about?

Comment: I am talking about the small down extreme button..

Comment: That does not help. How about circling it in the picture?

Comment: The title of your question isn't very relevant...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the button background is set to transparent (you can see the arm of the droid on top of the blue background).

Try setting android:background to some color and see what happens.

Another post I saw mentioned trying `android:background="@null"`, so maybe that will help instead of the color change.